# login only recognises password at second attempt

Tags: password, crashes, cache

On a Cubot Quest phone with android 9: Each time I reboot, the login screen does not accept my password at first attempt. It shows Wrong Password and immediately asks for a password again. At the second time the password is accepted. This happened about 100 times in a row.

This may be related to a bunch of other problems that started a few days ago: Apps crash repeatedly and the phone crash usually within 10 or so seconds. I tried to empty the cash of some Apps but next time I reboot the change has been reversed ie the old cash size is shown for the app; I tried to delete several apps, but after a reboot they are back again; if wifi or bluetooth or location etc are off and I switch them on, after a reboot they will be off again. Internal Memory is said to be 33% full. Ram I don't know.

Given the phone hangs up within 10 seconds debugging or backing up is obviously close to impossible.

Any ideas before a factory reset?

Comment: Based on your description a hardware defect could be the cause. It could be the flash memory or the battery. Both can cause problems like crashes or reboots. If writing to flash memory doesn't work anymore it could be because flash is defect and has switched to read-only mode or the battery is too weak to provide the write voltage. What happens if you connect the phone o a charger? Do the phone still act this way?

Comment: Same problem on charger.   I managed to open a Note in the yellow Note App, make a text edit and reboot before crashes started. The change was gone after the reboot. That may support the idea that the flash is in read-only mode.

Comment: To finalise this question: The phone stopped working completely a few days early into December 22. Wouldn't even switch on now. So, probably a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

To finalise this question: The phone stopped working completely a few days early into December 22. Wouldn't even switch on now. So, probably a hardware issue.